# How to get all child objects of a parent when data modeled across two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have two tables - Container and ContainerObjectRel

Container - High level objects are stored in DB

ContainerObjectRel - will hold immediate child (low level) objects of a container

Note that child object of a container can be a container itself or a leaf object.

Table structure is as follows:-

Container

```
CONTAINER_ID   UUID
```

ContainerObjectRel

```
OBJECT_ID  CONTAINER_ID UUID NAME CREATED_TIME
```

### Sample Data

[image: sample data]

When trying to achieve the shown desired output through recursive cte, given a container id, i came up with the following to retrieve only the immediate one level objects (which when observing would obviously not be the desired output)

```
WITH SUBORDINATES AS (

  SELECT 
    PARENTOBJECT.NAME AS NAME,
    PARENTOBJECT.CONTAINER_ID AS CONTAINER_ID, 
    PARENTOBJECT.UUID AS UUID 
  FROM CONTAINEROBJECTREL as PARENTOBJECT 
  WHERE PARENTOBJECT.CONTAINER_ID = 1

      UNION ALL

  SELECT
    CHILDOBJECT.NAME AS NAME,
    CHILDOBJECT.CONTAINER_ID AS CONTAINER_ID, 
    CHILDOBJECT.UUID AS UUID 
  FROM CONTAINEROBJECTREL as CHILDOBJECT 
  INNER JOIN SUBORDINATES AS PARENT ON PARENT.UUID=CHILDOBJECT.UUID
)
SELECT * 
from SUBORDINATES
```

I wish to avoid querying multiple times recursively in order to get all the leaf objects of a specified container. Hence, trying to address through recursive CTE.

Unsure on how to observe this problem I have in hand, any advice/hint would be useful.

### Known:

1. Rendering all the leaf objects of a container requires least usage in our application, when compared to the immediate one level objects (hence the data modeling)
2. problem has to be addressed for both postgres and mssql

Comment: I am guessing you need to `select from your_CTE` for the 2nd part of your `UNION`?

Comment: The code you show looks correct -- it will recurse all items in the tree.  How exactly is it not working?

Comment: @LONG -- he does do that -- he is joining to "SUBORDINATES"

Comment: @Hogan my bad eyesight...

Comment: well, it's running in an infinite loop, serving no data. And also, I believe it wouldn't provide the desired output.

Comment: @surendhar_s - as written it should not be an infinite loop -- even on the sub-set of data you showed us?   Maybe your data as a loop.  The code is correct if the data in your table is correct.  *remember the query after the union all will only join to data from the prior select not the entire table -- this is how recursive CTEs work.*

Comment: @Hogan Thanks.  "remember the query after the union all will only join to data from the prior select not the entire table -- this is how recursive CTEs work." - This indeed helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I made a mistake in reiterating the same table (CONTAINEROBJECTREL) in recursive term of CTE.

Here is the working version

```
WITH RECURSIVE SUBORDINATES AS (

SELECT CONTAINEROBJECTREL.GUID AS LEAF_GUID, CONTAINEROBJECTREL.NAME AS LEAF_NAME, CONTAINER.GUID AS PARENT_GUID 
FROM CONTAINER INNER JOIN CONTAINEROBJECTREL 
ON CONTAINER.CONTAINER_ID=CONTAINEROBJECTREL.CONTAINER_ID   
WHERE CONTAINER.CONTAINER_ID = 1 

UNION ALL   

SELECT CONTAINEROBJECTREL.GUID AS LEAF_GUID, CONTAINEROBJECTREL.NAME AS LEAF_NAME, CONTAINER.GUID AS PARENT_GUID 
FROM CONTAINER INNER JOIN CONTAINEROBJECTREL 
ON CONTAINER.CONTAINER_ID=CONTAINEROBJECTREL.CONTAINER_ID   
INNER JOIN SUBORDINATES ON SUBORDINATES.LEAF_GUID=CONTAINER.GUID ) 

SELECT *  from SUBORDINATES
```